# Callback recall itself

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a function that inserts into a database a random number in a column that is the primary key.

I have a problem when the number is already in the database I want to call the process again to change the number and try to insert again but I am a novice with Javascript so here is the code I have come up with so far.

Function that create a random number:

EDIT 2:

```
function crearNumero()
{ 
    var aNumeros = new Array
    (
        '1', '2', '3','4','5','6','7','8','9'
    ); 
    var cNumero = aNumeros[Math.floor(Math.random()*aNumeros.length)]; 


    return cNumero;
}
```

Function that inserts in to the database:

```
function insertarNumero(Callback)
{
  var sql='INSERT INTO tabla_numero(numero) VALUES(?)';
  var params= [crearNumero()];

  client.query(sql,params,function(err,rows)
  {
    if(err){
      arguments.callee(Callback);
    } else {
      return Callback(params[0]);
    }
  });
}
```

So I try to insert the number with this:

```
insertarNumero(function(args)
     {
       console.log('el numero ingresado fue '+args);
       console.log('the number inserted was '+args);
        });
```

This code is ok but when the number exists already I dont know how to repeat de process.

Can anyone give me an indication as to how I can go about solving this issue?

Comment: Isn't it very unsecure to execute mysql queries using JavaScript as it is executed on the client-side and everybody can change them?

Comment: @Birk I believe it's [node.js](http://nodejs.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to actually pass a callback function to the `insertarNumero` function, like so:

```
function anotherInsert() {
    insertarNumero(crearNumero(), anotherInsert);
}
```

This will cause the `insertarNumero` function to re-call this function, should it fail. Be advised that you should probably also check the error code so that you don't attempt to insert multiple times, if there was a connection error, for example.

**Edit**: Seeing as you're still having difficulty resolving your issue, here are two alternatives which might help you:

```
function insertarNumero(callback) {
    var sql = 'INSERT INTO tabla_numero(numero) VALUES(?)';
    var params = [crearNumero()];

    client.query(sql, params, function(err, rows) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err);
        } else {
            callback();
        }
    });
}

function insert() {
    insertarNumero(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('failed to insert');
            insert();
        } else {
            console.log('inserted');
        }
    });
}
```

And if you really don't want the `insert()` function...

```
function insertarNumero(callback) {
    var sql = 'INSERT INTO tabla_numero(numero) VALUES(?)';
    var params = [crearNumero()];

    client.query(sql, params, function(err, rows) {
        if (!err) {
            if (callback) {
                callback(params[0]);
            }
        } else {
            //TODO: Check the error code
            insertarNumero(callback);
        }
    });
}

insertarNumero(function(args) {
    console.log('the number inserted was ' + args);
});
```

Comment: yes i want to call the function insertarNumero if the number already exists in the db...

Comment: This does what you ask - when an error is thrown from inside `insertarNumero`, it will try again with a new number.

Comment: really?? i solve this like your first explanation and i was to post the solution... tnx for your time... i did the first example but more extend...

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is an auto increment instead of random numbers. This would be more comfortable.

If you really want to insert random numbers, you should create a `unique index` on `numero`. After calling your query, you could check if the query succeeded, if it did not, check whether it was because the number already existed. (Check the error number returned by the mysql server.) If it failed, you create a new random number and call your function again to insert the new number.

PS: At the moment, you could only store nine rows in your database.

Answer (score -1):

Just call itself again and pass same Callback using `arguments.callee`:

```
function insertarNumero(Callback)
{
  var sql='INSERT INTO tabla_numero(numero) VALUES(?)';
  var params= [crearNumero()];

  client.query(sql,params,function(err,rows)
  {
    if(err){
      arguments.callee(Callback);
    } else {
      return Callback();
    }
  });
}
```

`arguments.callee` is same as using this function's name `insertarNumero`

Comment: its worth noting (in case he doesn't realise) that this works because the sql query will fail if the primary key already exists.  I suspect he knows this already but just thought id mention it.

Comment: Well it's a silly idea to generate random numbers for PKs. He should use UUID or get autoincrement from the table. Otherwise it will end up in a damn long loop.

Comment: i dont understand this if(err){
      arguments.callee(Callback); what is arguments??

Comment: means if your SQL query is not successful, it will retry. `arguments.callee` is the actual function is you're executing. Basically it returns self. Try this in console: `var f = function() { console.log(arguments.callee) }()`

Comment: @andrescabana86 It's basic Javascript, man. http://devlicio.us/blogs/sergio_pereira/archive/2010/09/10/have-you-met-arguments-callee.aspx

Comment: yeah... sry for that im noob with nodejs and javascript, specially with web apps im a desktop programmer in argentina this is a little new for all the new programmers...

Comment: That's fine. Node.js comes pretty weird at first because of its async nature and constant need to use callbacks. My example will work but in general your idea of randomly generating primary keys is not a good one. Better rely on DB to autoincrement keys.

Comment: Are yoou sure arguments calee doesn't refer to the callback its in? And in any case, its usually clearer and more robust to just use the function names instead of requiring arguments.calee.

Comment: @missingno that's easy: You don't have to change it if you changed function name, and be sure that sooner or later it may happen. Also, you don't need to rely on exact set of original arguments if you don't change them, like in my example. You can simply do `arguments.callee(arguments)` vs. `someFunctionName(arg1, arg2, arg3... arg25)`

Comment: PS I am not saying you can't just call by function name -- it's just easier, especially if your function sits in some namespace and is declared with literal notation, e.g. `some.namespace.parent.child = { foo: function() {...}` in which case you would need to call it using the `some.namespace.parent.child.foo()`

Comment: i try... RangeError: Maximun call stack size exceeded

Comment: Well exactly )) I told you, you can't just use this approach because this process will become a bottle neck (already did). And in Node you can't do it without calling on itself until you have found an unused id. Don't reinvent the wheel, use your DB's primary key with auto incremenet.

Comment: i dont try to invent the wheel jajaja (lol..) i want to make a function that register a random number i a db wich is not in the db...

Comment: Haha, than why don't you do it in pure SQL like `INSERT INTO tabla_numero(numero) SELECT(ROUND(RAND() * 10))`?